# Defining the likelihood function in survival analysis using SAS

Tags: maximum-likelihood, survival, sas

I use `proc lifereg` procedure in SAS for survival analysis.
In order to understand the process behind this procedure, I am trying to code the likelihood function and minimize it using `proc nlp`.

Assume this is my dataset:

```
data data;
    input age year nodes failure;
    cards;
    30 6.4 1 1
    30 6.2 3 1
    30 6.5 0 1
    31 5.9 2 1
    31 6.5 4 1
    33 5.8 10 1
    33 6.0 0 1
    34 5.9 0 2
    34 6.6 9 2
    34 5.8 30 1
    34 6.0 1 1
    34 6.1 10 1
    34 6.7 7 1
    34 6.0 0 1
    35 6.4 13 1
    35 6.3 0 1
    36 6.0 1 1
    36 6.9 0 1
    37 6.0 0 1
    37 6.3 0 1
    37 5.8 0 1
    37 5.9 6 1
    37 6.0 15 1
    37 6.3 0 1
    38 6.9 21 2
    38 5.9 2 1
    38 6.0 0 1
    38 6.0 0 1
    38 6.2 3 1
    38 6.4 1 1
    38 6.6 0 1
    38 6.6 11 1
    38 6.0 1 1
    38 6.7 5 1
    39 6.6 0 2  
;
run;
```

And this is how I fit an exponential baseline hazard to the data:

```
proc lifereg data=data;
    model year*failure(1)=/dist=exponential;
run;
```

Now, to form the likelihood function, I need to define failure (f) and survival (S) functions. I had a look at [SAS support group](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_lifereg_sect019.htm), but I did not completely understand how f and S are defined. Anyhow, I coded the likelihood function as follows.

```
data parameter(type=est);  *Initializing the parameters;
        Keep _type_     Shape scale constant;
        _type_='parms'; Shape=1; scale=40; constant=1; 
        output;
run;

proc nlp data=data NOMISS tech=tr inest=parameter Pcov phes;
    max LL; 
    Parms   Shape scale constant;

    mu=constant;                  *Vector of covariates ;
    w=log(year/scale);            *This is my interpretation for w (It might be wrong);

    f = exp(w-mu)*exp(-exp(w-mu));
    S = exp(-exp(w-mu));

    likelihood = (f**(failure-1)) * (S**(2-failure));
    LL = log(likelihood);
run;
```

Now the problem is the values of parameters from minimizing my likelihood function are different from the outputs of `proc lifereg`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors in your code:

- There should be no scale and shape parameters in your parm statement simply because you are fitting an exponential distribution of which scale parameter $\sigma=1$ and no shape parameter. The output of proc lifereg have Weibull scale and shape shown because they are calculated as: weibull scale: $\eta= \exp(\mu)$ and weibull shape:$\beta=1/\sigma$.
- The specification of $w$ in your code is not correct: Even though for exponential distribution when $\sigma=1$ it is the same $\log(T_\epsilon)$. The correct understanding is that $w$ is the log transformed event time: $w=\log(T_\epsilon)$ and **NOT** logarithm of **scaled** event time.

The following code after correcting for the two points mentioned above will give the same results as proc lifereg (with rounding of the numbers):

```
proc nlp data=data tech=tr Pcov phes;
  max LL; 
  Parms mu;
  w=log(year);
  f = exp(w-mu)*exp(-exp(w-mu));
  S = exp(-exp(w-mu));
  likelihood = (f**(failure-1)) * (S**(2-failure));
  LL = log(likelihood);
run;

                                     Parameter Estimates
N Parameter Estimate Approx Std Err  t Value   Approx Pr>|t| Gradient Obj Func
1 mu        3.999116 0.474880        8.421311  7.818057E-10  0.000007476

                      Value of Objective Function = -12.51585779
```